# Хороший стиль речи

Tags: алгоритм

Участник форума Вова очень любит писать сообщения, опуская пробелы после знаков препинания и забывая ставить заглавные буквы в начале предложения (ему почему-то кажется, что это придает его сообщениям особый шарм). Модераторы уже устали делать замечания Вове и решили попросить программистов форума написать простейший корректор, который будет расставлять пробелы и делать буквы заглавными за Вову.

Правила исправлений таковы:

1. Предложения состоят из слов, пробелов, кавычек, знаков препинания, переводов строк.
2. Слова состоят из букв русского и латинского алфавита.
3. Предложения заканчиваются точкой, восклицательными или вопросительным знаком.
4. Первое слово в предложении должно начинаться с заглавной буквы, все остальные буквы в предложении должны быть строчными.
5. Перед каждым знаком препинания (запятая, точка, восклицательный и вопросительный знак, двоеточие, многоточие) не должно быть пробела, после каждого знака препинания должен быть пробел.

Предложите свой вариант корректора. На вход подается текст, на выходе получается текст.

Comment: А зачем вообще задавать нам эти задания?

Comment: > Участник форума Вова очень любит писать сообщения, опуская пробелы после знаков препинания и забывая ставить заглавные буквы в начале предложения (ему почему-то кажется, что это придает его сообщениям особый шарм). Модераторы уже устали делать замечания Вове и решили попросить программистов форума написать простейший корректор, который будет расставлять пробелы и делать буквы заглавными за Вову.

зачем переходить на личности? =)

Comment: @GLmonster На ваш вопрос найдется [ответ в блоге](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2012/07/blog-post.html).

Comment: Я так и знал, что Вова очень ограниченный, даже в использовании знаков препинания (ну это исходя из 1ого ответа - видимо это знакомый...тссс). Вова у нас не использует прямую речь, да даже всякие скобочки, а это на форуме - ну вы сами понимаете; плюс не разделяет длинные предложения, состоящие из частей, разных по смысловой нагрузке, точкой с запятой!
да черт с Вовой и ответами... самым простым способом будет банить таких "Вов"

Comment: Возможно не уместны, но правила созданы не для того, чтобы их нарушали "Вовы"

Comment: Задача классная. Но убогая. Например, отсутствует функция определения сокращений. Ясно, что для сокращений свои правила написания и после них предложение как может продолжаться дальше, так и закачиваться. Так же не проводится анализ на имена собственные и их формы.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re

def correction(text):
    def callback(m):
        punct, word = m.groups()
        word = word.capitalize() if punct in ('.', '!', '?', '') else word.lower()
        return '%s %s' % (punct if punct else '', word)

    return re.sub(u'\s*(^|[.!?,:\s]|\.\.\.)?\s*([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+|$)', callback, text, re.U)
```

Проверяем как работает:

```
>>> print(correction(u'раз ,два, три , четыре, ПЯТЬ - вышел ZaIcHiK погулять.ТУТ охотник выбегает ...прямо в зайчика СТРЕЛЯЕТ ! КОНЕЦ .'))

Раз, два, три, четыре, пять - вышел zaichik погулять. Тут охотник выбегает... прямо в зайчика стреляет! Конец.
```

Comment: Питон? Зер гуд, Вольдемар, зер гуд (с)

Comment: А разбивка по строкам и отступы в начале строки сохранятся?

Comment: Вообще-то после троеточия должна быть большая буква

Comment: Опять же, а что насчет кавычек и скобок?

Comment: :) признали ответ лучшим и сразу началась критика, а до этого двое суток спокойно висел :)

Comment: @avp, не сохраняются, поскольку в задаче такого условия не было. Однако разбивку строк можно сохранить если в регулярке заменить `\s` на пробел. С отступами сложнее, но тоже можно.

@FAndES,

> Предложения заканчиваются точкой, восклицательными или вопросительным знаком.

Про много точи тут не сказано.

@Sleeping Owl, а что с ними?

Answer (score 6):

```
use utf8;
sub correct{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/(\w+)/\L$1/g;
    $string =~ s/(\w+)\s*([.,!?:]+)\s*/$1$2 /g;
    $string =~ s/(\A|[.!?]+)(\s*)(\w+)/$1$2\u$3/g;
    return $string;
}
print correct "раз ,два, три , четыри, ПЯТЬ - вышел ZaIcHiK погулять!ТУТ охотник выбегает ...прямо в зайчика СТРЕЛЯЕТ ? КОНЕЦ .";
```

Результат : *Раз, два, три, четыри, пять - вышел zaichik погулять! Тут охотник выбегает... Прямо в зайчика стреляет? Конец.*

P.S позаимствовал пример для теста у [Ilya Pirogov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1797/ilya-pirogov), надеюсь он не обидеться :)
P.S Это решение на **Perl**

Answer (score 2):

На PHP:

```
function corrector($string){
    $string=strtolower($string);
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/ *\. */';
    $patterns[1] = '/ *\, */';
    $patterns[2] = '/ *\! */';
    $patterns[3] = '/ *\? */';
    $patterns[4] = '/ *\: */';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = '. ';
    $replacements[1] = ', ';
    $replacements[2] = '! ';
    $replacements[3] = '? ';
    $replacements[4] = ': ';
    $string=preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
    $string=preg_replace('/\. \. \. /', '... ', $string);

    $string=preg_replace_callback(
            '/([\.\!\?]|(\.\.\.)) [a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/',
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'
            ),
            $string
        );

    $string=preg_replace_callback(
            '/^ *[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/',
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'
            ),
            $string
        );
    return $string;
}
$string="   test   .  ..test   ?teSt    .";
echo corrector($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string Corrector(string innerText, UserInfo userInfo)

{

   var reg1 = new Regex(@"[\.\,\:\!\?][^\s]"); //после знака препинания нет пробела или переноса    
   var reg2 = new Regex(@"[\.]\ [^А-ЯA-Z]"); //после точки и пробела не заглавная буква    
   var reg3 = new Regex(@"\b[^А-ЯA-Z]"); //после переноса строки не заглавная буква
   var reg4 = new Regex(@"\ [\.\,\:\!\?]"); //пробел перед знаком препинания

   if(reg1.IsMatch(innerText) || reg2.IsMatch(innerText) 
      || reg3.IsMatch(innerText) || reg4.IsMatch(innerText))    
   {    
        return("Прошу прощения, товарищи. К сожалению, я безнадежно безграмотная соволочь! В связи с этим, не имею возможности в письменном виде высказать вам свою мысль.");    
   }

   return innerText;    
}
```

Comment: 1) reg2 я бы поправил - почему после точки только один пробел, а не больше, или не перевод строки? + см далее:

2) reg3 не очень понятен (например, стихи в столбик), ну и предложения могут начинаться не только с букв :-) Но это уже претензия к условию 4

Comment: reg3 означает на самом деле любой символ кроме большой буквы справа от границы слова, но так как справа не может быть ни буквы ни цифры, иначе это была бы не граница слова, то это выражение задает любую границу слова, кроме той которая в конце строки.  
reg2, предложение может начинаться с цифры, а оно это режет.

Comment: 1. Забыли про кавычки, скобки и тире.
2. После знака препинания может идти другой знак препинания: после точки - другая точка, например.

Comment: в рег3 я опечитался, там \n должно было быть. А вообще, я же раздул, подсоны

Comment: Бейсик, что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось на `java + oop` без `regexp`. Закодить различное форматирование для дефисов и тире банально не хватило терпения =/

```
input string (для наглядности строки в кавычках):
'   hello DUMMY-user  !    a lot of thanks  ,-      this is a "Hello World" Text ...  just   
to check   '

result string:
'Hello dummy - user! A lot of thanks, - this is a "hello world" text... just 
to check.'
```

`USE_CUSTOM_FORMATTERS` - рубильник дополнительных форматтеров, которые нужны, но не были явно оговорены в условии задачи

```
public class FormatStr {
    // debug mode switcher - dump results after each formatter
    private static boolean DEBUG = false;

    // additional formatters switcher - use additional formatters
    private static boolean USE_CUSTOM_FORMATTERS = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create list
    List<ABaseFormatter> formatters = new LinkedList<ABaseFormatter>();

    // add extra formatters
    if (USE_CUSTOM_FORMATTERS) {
        formatters.add(new DashFormatter());
        formatters.add(new TrimStringFormatter());
        formatters.add(new RemoveExtraWhitespacesFormatter());
    }

    // add required formatters
    formatters.add(new LastDotFormatter());
    formatters.add(new StringToLowerCaseFormatter());
    formatters.add(new FirstCharToCapitalFormatter());
    formatters.add(new SentenceFromUpperCaseCharFormatter());
    formatters.add(new BeforePunctMarkFormatter());
    formatters.add(new AfterPunctMarkFormatter());

    // input str
    String str = "   hello DUMMY-user  !    a lot of thanks  ,-      this is a \"Hello World\" Text ...  just   \nto check   ";

    dump("input string:", str);

    String result = str;
    for (ABaseFormatter sf : formatters) {
        result = sf.format(result);
        if (DEBUG) {
        dump("applied formatter " + sf.getClass().getName(), result);
        }

    }

    dump("result string:", result);
    }

    private static void dump(final String purpose, final String str) {
    System.out.println(purpose + "\n'" + str + "'\n");
    }
}

abstract class ABaseFormatter {
    // private Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    public static Set<Character> SENTENCE_SEPARATOR_CHARS = new HashSet<Character>();
    public static Set<Character> PUNCTUATION_CHARS = new HashSet<Character>();

    static {
    Collections.addAll(SENTENCE_SEPARATOR_CHARS, '.', '!', '?');
    Collections.addAll(PUNCTUATION_CHARS, ',', '.', '!', '?', ':');
    }

    /**
     * Format string
     * 
     * @param string
     */
    public final String format(String string) {
    if (null == string) {
        return null;
    }

    return formatStr(string);
    }

    /**
     * Override to apply formatting to whole string
     * 
     * @param str
     */
    protected String formatStr(String str) {
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(str);

    // default behavior - apply per character formatting
    for (int i = 0; i < buff.length();) {
        i = formatChar(buff, i, buff.charAt(i));
    }

    return buff.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Override to apply formatting per char
     * 
     * @param buff
     * @param pos
     * @param ch
     */
    protected int formatChar(StringBuilder buff, int pos, char ch) {
    return pos + 1;
    }
}

class SentenceFromUpperCaseCharFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    protected int formatChar(StringBuilder buff, int pos, char ch) {
    if (pos == 0) {
        // find first letter if possible
        while (pos < buff.length()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(buff.charAt(pos))) {
            buff.setCharAt(pos, Character.toUpperCase(buff.charAt(pos)));
            break;
        }
        pos++;
        }
    }

    return pos + 1;
    }

}

class AfterPunctMarkFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    protected int formatChar(StringBuilder buff, int pos, char ch) {
    // add whitespace after punctuation mark
    if (PUNCTUATION_CHARS.contains(ch)) {
        // if dots are coming just move to next one
        if ('.' != ch) {
        // add whitespace between punct mark and word
        ch = buff.charAt(pos + 1);
        if (' ' != ch && '\n' != ch) {
            buff.insert(pos + 1, ' ');
        }
        }
    }

    return pos + 1;
    }
}

class BeforePunctMarkFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    protected int formatChar(StringBuilder str, int pos, char ch) {
    // delete leading whitespaces before punctuation marks
    if (PUNCTUATION_CHARS.contains(ch)) {
        // count leading whitespaces to the punctuation mark;
        for (int start = pos; start > 1; start--) {
        char prevCh = str.charAt(start - 1);
        if (' ' != prevCh && '\n' != prevCh) {
            str.replace(start, pos, "");
            pos = start + 1;
            break;
        }
        }

        // new sentence should start from upper case letter
        if (SENTENCE_SEPARATOR_CHARS.contains(ch)
            && (pos > 0 && str.charAt(pos - 1) != '.')) {
        // find first letter if possible
        while (pos < str.length()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(pos))) {
            str.setCharAt(pos,
                Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(pos)));
            break;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        }
    }

    return pos + 1;
    }
}

class LastDotFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {

    @Override
    protected String formatStr(String str) {
    // default behavior - apply per character formatting
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (SENTENCE_SEPARATOR_CHARS.contains(ch)) {
        break;
        }

        // add end of sentence char to the last character
        // of the last sentence
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
        return str + '.';
        }
    }
    return str;
    }

}

class FirstCharToCapitalFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    public String formatStr(String string) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(0)) + string.substring(1);
    }
}

class RemoveExtraWhitespacesFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    public String formatStr(String string) {
    while (-1 != string.indexOf("  ")) {
        string = string.replaceAll("  ", " ");
    }
    return string;
    }
}

class StringToLowerCaseFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    public String formatStr(String string) {
    return string.toLowerCase();
    }
}

class TrimStringFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    public String formatStr(String string) {
    return string.trim();
    }
}

class DashFormatter extends ABaseFormatter {
    @Override
    protected int formatChar(StringBuilder buff, int pos, char ch) {
    // delete leading whitespaces before dashes
    if ('-' == ch) {
        // add white space before dash
        ch = buff.charAt(pos - 1);
        if (pos > 1 && ' ' != ch && '\n' != ch) {
        buff.insert(pos, ' ');
        }

        // add whitespace after
        pos = pos + 1;
        ch = buff.charAt(pos + 1);
        if (pos + 1 < buff.length() && (' ' != ch && '\n' != ch)) {
        buff.insert(pos + 1, ' ');
        }
    }

    return pos + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**А я решил реализовать это на C++**. Может, Хэшкоду полезно будет, кто знает...несмотря на то, что задача почти элементарная( и, думаю, стандартная ). Я сделал все через классы( ну а как же еще!? ), поэтому можно встраивать в любые системы, не вдаваясь в подробности функционирования этого класса, зная лишь одни его методы. Инкапсуляция, соответственно. Да и вообще, такие вещи не разумно реализовывать не через классы, так как тут имеется свое поведение. Прошу любить и жаловать:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<clocale>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Corrector  // наш класс, реализующий функционал корректора
{
private:
    char* filename; // имя файла, где лежит BAD-TEXT.
    std::string text;    // текст из этого файла
    std::vector<std::string>lines; // все лексемы( Tok = ' ')
    void CreateText()
    {
        for(vector<string>::iterator itr=lines.begin();itr!=lines.end();++itr)
        text+=*itr+" ";
        transform(text.begin(),text.end(),text.begin(),tolower);
        text[0] = toupper(text[0]);
        Correct();
    }
public:
    Corrector(char* fn):filename(fn){setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");}
    void LoadText()  // метод загрузки текста
    {
        std::string str;
        ifstream f(filename);
        while(!f.eof())
        {
            f>>str;
            lines.push_back(str);
        }
        f.close();
        CreateText();
    }

    void Correct() // корректор исходного текста
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(string::iterator itr=text.begin();itr!=text.end();++itr)
        {
        i++;
        if(*itr==',' || *itr=='!' || *itr=='?' || *itr=='.' || *itr==';') 
            if(i>0) if(*(itr+1)!=' ') text.insert(itr+1,' ');

        if(*itr=='!' || *itr=='?' || *itr=='.') 
            if(i>0) if(*(itr-1)==' ') text.erase(itr-1,itr);

        if(i>2) if(*(itr-2)=='!' || *(itr-2)=='?' || *(itr-2)=='.')  
            *itr = toupper(*itr);
        }
    }

    void SaveText(char* fn)  // Сохранение отформатированного текста в Файл "fn"
    {
    ofstream f(fn);
    f<<text<<endl;
    f.close();
    }

    void Print(){cout<<text<<endl;} // отладочный метод...

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    Corrector corr("badtext.txt");  // корректор
    corr.LoadText();    // загружаем текст
    corr.Print();       // отладочный вызов
    corr.SaveText("formatted.txt");
    system("Pause");
}
```

**Скажем, если исходный текст был таким:**

```
когда-то я был таким же шалопаем,как и вы,поэтому приношу свои извинения !!    
совершенно безграмотная сволочь(нет,нет,нет!) но а вы,а !? Так,что,"довай,до 
свыдааания!" !!!
```

**То на выходе он получается таким:**

```
Когда-то я был таким же шалопаем, как и вы, поэтому приношу свои извинения!!   
Совершенно безграмотная сволочь(нет, нет, нет! ) но а вы, а!? Так, что, "довай, до    
свыдааания! "!!!
```

---

Код писан в буквальном смысле "на коленке", поэтому, если будут обнаружены ошибки, я их исправлю...

**P.S**   Прошу прощения за громоздкость, но таков C++...тем не менее плохого ничего - код полностью встраиваем и масштабируем. Жду замечаний ( по стилю в том числе! )=)))

**А Вову за это банить надо**

Comment: Интересно, ребят, за что минус был? Кто-то поставил. Поясните лучше, где, что не так.

Comment: @Аsen, Вам не кажется, что на выходе получается текст хуже, чем на входе? Пробелы перед закрывающей скобкой, перед закрывающей кавычкой. А перед открывающей скобкой, наоборот, пробела нет.

Comment: @Asen, Вы все пробелы и пустые строки (т.е. *авторскую* структуру текста) теряете. 

В ТЗ  такое не предусматривалось.

Comment: @Sleeping Owl, нет, мне так не кажется)

---
@avp, это специально так сделано, чтобы преобразовывать множество пробелов в один.

Comment: @Asen, что значит "кажется"? Я вижу, что написано в вашем результате. Там присутствуют все обозначенные мной ошибки (которых в исходной строке не было).

Comment: @Asen, IMHO это не специально, а потому что проще. Скажите еще, что вывод **всего** текста в одну строку, это не баг, а фича.

Но Вы не огорчайтесь, результат победителя не лучше (хотя значительно компактней).

Comment: @Sleeping Owl, да, есть пару багов которые вы указали, но на выходе получается что-то более лучшее, чем на входе, согласитесь) Этот код писан "на коленке", так, что отсутствие багов невозможно). 

---
@avp, да, Python таков =)